Used the same runner from the previous to the current
How can I retrieve the previous "Runner" and use it for the following job?
For example, if I run the first job (build_job1), I'd like to use the same runner for the second job (build_job2).
Job: build_job1
Duration: 46 seconds
Finished: 14 minutes ago
Queued: 0 seconds
Timeout: 1h (from project)
Runner: #44 (FxbdSaRNP) hwc-test-runner-1
Tags: docker

build_job1:
    stage: build
    tags:
        - test1
    script:
    - echo "===== Download starts ====="
    - echo "===== Download Ends ====="


build_job2:
    stage: build
    tags:
    - test2
    script:
    - echo "===== Download starts ====="
    - echo "===== Download Ends ====="

Because we have two runners running, I want to retag the docker with the same runner and container.

You can't: jobs are designed to potentially run on different runners. Can you explain why you need 2 jobs to run on the same runner? Maybe artifacts could be useful if you're looking to share data.

sir @GaëlJ, can I use the same runner and container? Because I want to docker tag everything so that it is not visible to other projects.

I have no idea what you mean. Why not a single job if you absolutely need to reuse same runner?

This is only one example, but we have numerous stages and not just two jobs. Sir @GaëlJ is it feasible to reuse the prior job?
